# Entity Framework 6 - Select Parents Where Children Equal

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I just need Parent objects. In SQL, this is simple:

```
select distinct * from parent 
join child on child.ParentID = Parent.ID 
where child.playssoccer = true;
```

In Entity Framework 6, this seems like splitting the atom to me.

I need new p => parent where parents.children.playssoccer = true .

How do I get soccer parents out of a similar EF6 DBContext?

Comment: Thanks, everybody! Paul Abbott's answer worked for me, so I'm giving him the checkmark. Everybody gets upvote, tho. I appreciate the timely responses.

Comment: Actually your question isn't about EF , it's about Linq usage: )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from p in context.Parents
where p.Children.Any(c => c.PlaySoccer == true)
select p
```

This is assuming you want parents who have at least one child that plays soccer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have navigation properties you can do something like

```
Parents.Where(p => p.child.playsoccer)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Parents
.Where(p=> p.child.playsoccer)
.GroupBy(p=> p.Parent.ID)
```